# Unable to properly create JPanel from a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to create a JPanel that pops up on the frame when a specific action occurs. The JFrame and JPanel are created in two separate classes and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to properly utilize them. When I run the code right now, when the action occurs, only a tiny JPanel appears in the top corner of the JFrame and it only displays the basic mac exit, minimize, and maximize buttons.

The code with the JFrame

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame
{
    private JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Robber - Main menu");
    private JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("Robber - Game");
    private final int WINDOW_SIZE_WIDTH = 905;
    private final int WINDOW_SIZE_HEIGHT = 940;

    public  void setMainFrame()
    {
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mainFrame.setSize(900,900);

        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
    }

    public void setGameFrame()
    {
        gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        gameFrame.setSize(WINDOW_SIZE_WIDTH, WINDOW_SIZE_HEIGHT);

        gameFrame.setResizable(false);
    }
    public void endGame()
    {
    NameBox name = new NameBox();
    name.setVisible(true);
    gameFrame.add(name);
```

The code with the JPanel is

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class NameBox extends JPanel implements KeyListener
{
    private String name;
    private JTextField userInput = new JTextField(10);
    private JPanel centerPanel;
    private JLabel centerText;

    public NameBox()
    {
        centerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 15, 15));
        centerText = new JLabel("<html><center>" +"0"+ "<br /><center>Enter your name</html>" , JLabel.CENTER);
        centerText.setFont(new Font("Britannic Bold", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        centerText.setForeground(new Color(230,180,14));

        centerPanel.add(centerText);
        setLocation(327,407);
        setSize(250, 125);

        userInput.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt)
            {
                if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    submitAction();
                }
            }
        });
        centerPanel.add(userInput);
        Box theBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        theBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        theBox.add(centerPanel);
        add(theBox);
    }
    public void submitAction()
    {
        name = userInput.getText();
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new NameBox().setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){}

}
```

If anyone could help me with my probably very poorly constructed code, that would be amazing!

Comment: Please don't use a `KeyListener` on text components, ever, for `JTextField` use an `ActionListener`, that's what it's designed for

Comment: Based on my understand of your problem, it sounds more like you want to use some kind `JDialog` to display a popup window

Comment: @MadProgrammer about your first comment, So even if I want it to detect when the user pushes enter, I should still instead use ActionListeners?

Comment: Yes, the "expected action" can be different on different platforms, so not all users may use [Enter] to "action" the field

Comment: Put it this way. You find a big empty field(the field is like the `JFrame`). You then build a village in that field(add a `JPanel` to that `JFrame`). But wait! you need some villagers, so you put villagers in the village(`JButtons`, `JTextAreas` and more). ------- Your problem is here: You have a village, but no space for it, because you do not have a field to put it in. You have to find a field(make a `JFrame`) to put your village(`JPanel`) in, or it will not exist.

Comment: here is a good [visual aid](https://s23.postimg.org/t77gt4bbv/square.jpg) to help you remember this

Answer (score 1):

A `JPanel` can not be display in of itself, it needs to be added to some container, which is, eventually, attached to some kind of window, before it can be displayed on the screen.  From what I can understand of our problem, you want to use some kind of dialog, see [How to make dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

As a rough and ready example...

```
public void endGame()
{
    NameBox name = new NameBox();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(gameFrame, name);
    gameFrame.add(name);
```